# Netzke Has many relation and rails fields_for

Tags: extjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, netzke

I have a simple `has_many` relation that can be implemented by rails `fields_for`. I am looking for the same behavior for `Netzke`.

Here is the classes:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title
  validates_presence_of :title, :description

  has_many :question_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_options
```

end

```
class QuestionOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :question
  validates_presence_of :title

  belongs_to :question
```

end

Here is the form I am building:

```
class QuestionForm < Netzke::Basepack::Form

  js_configure do |c|
    c.mixin
  end

  def configure(c)
    super
    record.build_for_editing if record.present?
    c.model = 'Question'
    c.title = 'Question'
    c.items = [:title, :description]
  end    
end
```

Upto this point form is working fine. I can't figure out the way to implement has_many behavior like we do in rails `fields_for`

Can any one guide me how to use `netzke` for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to implement master-detail/one-to-many editing? If so, the good example is given in Netzke demo application (see Bosses and Clerks in http://netzke-demo.herokuapp.com/).

You need to create three components:

- Question component (master) inheriting from Netzke::Basepack::Grid
- QuestionOption component (details) inheriting from
- Netzke::Basepack::Grid Composite component combining previous two
  components and adding some JavaScript to sync them.

First, QuestionOption model must allow access to the ID of the master table (Netzke thing, without that it will not work).

```
class QuestionOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :question_id
  validates_presence_of :title
  belongs_to :question
end
```

This is the components code:

```
class Questions < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Question'
    c.items = [
      :description,
      :title
    ]
  end
end

class QuestionOptions < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super

    c.strong_default_attrs = {question_id: c.question_id}
    c.scope = {question_id: c.question_id}

    c.model = 'QuestionOption'
    c.columns = [
      { name: :title, header: 'Option Title'}
    ]
  end
end

class QuestionsAndOptions < Netzke::Base
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.items = [:questions, :question_options]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.layout = :border
    c.border = false
    c.height = '100%'

    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function() {
        this.callParent();
        var questions = this.netzkeGetComponent('questions');
        var question_options = this.netzkeGetComponent('question_options');

        questions.on('itemclick', function(view, record) {
          this.selectQuestion(record.get('id'));
          question_options.getStore().load();
        }, this);
      }
    JS
  end

  endpoint :select_question do |id, this|
    component_session[:selected_question_id] = id
  end

  component :questions do |c|
    c.region = :center
  end

  component :question_options do |c|
    c.region = :south
    c.question_id = component_session[:selected_question_id]
    c.height = '50%'
  end
end
```

Please try and let me know if this is what you need. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Regards

Drazen

Comment: Hello Drazen, I actually ended up on this solution, but my requirement was something different. As you already know the mechanism of how we build `has_many` relation forms in rails. We use `fields_for` form builder and good gems like `coocoon` helps us to add links like `Add more`, plz check this reference https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/views/projects/_form.html.slim#L16. I was looking for similar solution in Netzke.